# After updates, I'm getting error in Titanium Studio

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

As I get notify  `node.js` requiring a new version. I have updated the **Titanium** to latest version. After updated and restarted my **Titanim Studio**, i'm getting this error while running my app in iPhone simulater

> [ERROR] Invalid --ios-version value '5.0'
>
> Accepted values:

**Titanium iPhone Simulator configuration**

[image: Titanium iPhone Simulator]

Then I have reinstalled my **Titanim Studio** now, i'm getting this error :

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.0.0 (12/12/12 18:49 a5894b3)
[INFO] iPhone Device family: iphone
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 5.0
[INFO] iPhone simulated device: iphone
[INFO] Performing full rebuild. This will take a little bit. Hold tight...
[INFO] Minimum iOS version: 4.3 Linked iOS Version 5.0 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.0.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1374, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr,kroll_coverage)],False)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.0.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1281, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.0.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Comment: If you run "titanium info -t ios" from the command line, what versions of XCode and iOS SDKs do you see it returns?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your input. I have reinstalled my titanium, now i'm getting this error `[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.0.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1374, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr,kroll_coverage)],False)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.0.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1281, in execute_xcode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Ti 3.0.0 is used only for ios 6.0. u cant run it in application of less than ios 6.0.

so this error is due to that. 3.0.0 support only ios 6

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed this error, by installing lower SDK version 2.0.7

Comment: 2.1.4 is stable it run everywhere try that